# Kendo Angular 2 version

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Can anyone tell me which version of the kendo grid are you guys using at [Master-Detail Grids](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/hierarchy/) for kendo grid with angular 2? I updated my version to 0.15.0 with all other dependencies and still not able to see this working.

Interestingly, I do have this working locally in a plunker @

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHneCVKWjPbhlTcxn35A?p=preview)

Please note it uses my local Urls so it might not be working for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detail feature is supported since the first version of the grid, so 0.15 should definitely support it. The plunkr is not really useful as it does not work. Make sure that you have correctly configured the grid, as if it works in plunkr it should work locally as well, as the scripts are practically the same.

Comment: interesting find - I had to change my selectors in angular  for the detailed grid from <accepted-Properties> to <acceptedproperties> locally and things work like a charm. I am not sure why and how it still works on the plunker. Thanks for the quick reply knikolov.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.0 is out. An upgrade to Angular 4 is needed to use latest stable version.